# How can I scale down a image down to a particular dimension size in Bootstrap V3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I have a  large image, in terms of dimensions 1000x250px, that I want to use as a logo for my page. My question is, how can I scale down the image accordingly to a reduced sized, so it fits better within the layout. Say to a size of 500x80px?

Hope someone can help!

Comment: Use Photoshop or something? If you just change something in the HTML/CSS, the client still will have to download the whole huge image...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the width attribute of images. This will scale your image (but the size will remain big as mb21 told you).

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
    <img src='myImg' style="width:50%; height:31%" />
```

But you won't be able to keep the ratio...

Think the best way still to modify your image with something like Gimp...

Answer (score 0):

Here how you can resize an image with CSS without detororiating the quality of the image.

**HTML**

```
/* Containing Elelment */

      <div id="logo-base"> 

       <img src="your-logo-image-url" />

     </div><!-- End Logo Base -->
```

**CSS**

```
/* Containing Element CSS */

     #logo-base {
     width: 200px; /* Your chosen height */
     height: auto; /* Must be auto */
    }

    /* Logo image CSS */

     #logo-base img {
     width: 100%; /* Must be 100% */
     height: auto; /* Must be auto */
    }
```

Here's how the above works: We adhere to the width(100%) of the containing DIV but we allow it to stretch as it desires, that way the resize process is proportional. The more you reduce the width of the containing DIV, the more the height of logo reduces to the proper ratio.